# Remotely sync Time Machine drives

Tags: rsync, time-machine, xserve, backup

I have an Xserve that runs Time Machine to a local terabyte drive.  I also connected my external terabyte drive for a time period and had Time Machine use it to establish the seed data.

I plan to take my drive back home with me (out of state) and have the Xserve return to using its local drive for Time Machine.  But when I get back home, is there a way to keep my external drive's copy of the Time Machine Backups folder in sync with the Backups folder back on the Xserve?  I'm wanting a full copy of the history (makes an awesome remote backup).

I've thought of using the unix command rsync.  In fact, that's how I had been doing it but I was looking the compactness that Time Machine was able to achieve.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rsync should work fine for keeping the new xserve generated deltas current on your remote drive -- as long as you're only pulling from the xserve and not trying to push changes you make on the remote drive back to the xserve's time machine...

If you want bi-directional file synchonization (something like unison might provide that) I don't think that's going to play nice with time machine.